# SEO Question - Google not getting past cookies?

Tags: seo

I'm completely stumped on an SEO issue and could really use some direction from an expert. We built a website recently, http://www.ecovinowines.net and because it is all about wine, we set up an age verification that requires the user to click before entering the site. By using cookies, we prevent the user from accessing any page in the site before clicking the age verification link. It's been a couple of months since launching the site so I thought I'd check out some keywords on google. I just typed in the name of the website to see what pages would be indexed and it is only showing the age verification pages. From the googling I've done, apparently nothing behind the age verification will be visible to the google bots because they ignore cookies.

Is there no safe workaround for this? I checked out New Belgium's site, which uses a similar age verification link, and all of it's pages seem to be getting indexed. Once you click on one of it's links from google, it redirects the user to the age verification page. Are they not using cookies? Or how might they be getting around the cookie bot issue.

Comment: Can you try detecting if a search engine is visiting the site and let them through?

Answer (score 1):

Do a test for Google bot's User agent and allow access if it matches. You might want to let other search engines through too...

> Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)
>
> msnbot/1.0 (+http://search.msn.com/msnbot.htm)
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Yahoo! Slurp; http://help.yahoo.com/help/us/ysearch/slurp)
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
>
> ia_archiver

Answer (score 1):

Semi-official response from the Google:

> This topic comes up periodically for sites (alcohol, porn, etc.) that 
>   need to serve an age verification notice on every page. What we 
>   recommend in this case is to serve it via JavaScript. That way users 
>   can see the age verification any time they try to access your content, 
>   but search engines that don't run JavaScript won't see the warning and 
>   will instead be able to see your content.

- http://groups.google.com/group/Google_Webmaster_Help-Tools/browse_thread/thread/3ce6c0b3cc72ede8/

I think a more modern technique would be to render all the content normally, then obscure it with a Javascript overlay.

I had a quick look at New Belgium and it's not clear what they're doing. Further investigation needed.

Comment: This seems like a good solution that I've noticed on a few sites, like the Jim Beam site. However, because my site is already set up more like the New Belgium site, should I feel okay about using Rich's approach identifying the bots? It would be my preference to use that approach for this project but I want to make sure others don't feel it might be risking getting blacklisted from Google.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using PHP, something like this will do the job. You'd need to add other bots if you want them.

```
$isBot = strpos($_SERVER[‘HTTP_USER_AGENT’],"Googlebot");
```

Then you can toggle your age verification on or off based on that variable.

Comment: I am using PHP. I've read a little about cloaking and how google frowns on it and won't index sites at all that use a cloaking technique - is the PHP you provided a cloaking technique and if so, should I expect any negative treatment from google by using it? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You could use it as cloaking, but you aren't – arguably you are doing the opposite! Cloaking might be showing a normal user the page, but showing Google a huge list of keywords.